# How to calculated grade then pass to blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

I have table named **SCORE** which has column name **Result**,i want to apply grade computation based on the value from **RESULT** like this

```
if('result'>=90)
{grade=A+}
```

**This is my grade conversion**

90% to 100% (A+),80% to 89% (A),70% to 79% (B),60% to 69% (C),50% to 59% (D),40% to 49% (E),30% to 39% (F),20% to 29% (G),28% to 0% (N/A),null(W)

**note** I don't know how to do this inside my controller and pass to blade

**Controller:**

```
public function index($id)
  {

    $leads=Lead::findorFail($id);
    $scores = Score::with('lead','subject')->where('lead_id','=',$id)->get();

    $from = date('2018-01-01');
    $to = date('2018-03-31');
    $atnds = DB::table('attendances')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, status'))
                     ->where('status', '=', 'P')
                     ->whereBetween('days', [$from,$to])
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->where('lead_id', '=', $id)
                     ->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.pdf', compact(['scores','atnds','leads']));
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');



    return $pdf->stream('data.pdf');
  }
```

View

```
@foreach($scores as $score)
```

```
<td>&nbsp;{{$score->subject->subject_name}}</td>
<td>&nbsp;{{$score->result}}</td>
<td>&nbsp;{{This where i want to put grade}}</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

@endforeach

Comment: add simple if, else condition in your blade

Comment: can use multiple if statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **highly** recommend you do not do this in the view, and instead do the calculation in the model or in a lib somewhere.

Assuming you do this in the Score model, you can do something like this:

```
public function getGrade() {
    if(is_null($this->result)){ return 'W'; }
    if($this->result >= 90) { return 'A+'; }
    if($this->result < 90 && $this->result >= 80) { return 'A'; }   
    if($this->result < 80 && $this->result >= 70) { return 'B'; }   
    if($this->result < 70 && $this->result >= 60) { return 'C'; }   
    if($this->result < 60 && $this->result >= 50) { return 'D'; }   
    if($this->result < 50 && $this->result >= 40) { return 'E'; }   
    if($this->result < 40 && $this->result >= 30) { return 'F'; }   
    if($this->result < 30 && $this->result >= 20) { return 'G'; }   
    if($this->result < 20) { return 'N/A'; }        
}
```

Then in your view call it like so:

```
$score->getGrade();
```

Comment: can i apply this in my current controller?

Comment: You can copy and paste that snippet I wrote into your Score model and it should run

Comment: sir this code showing error if(is_null($this->result){ return 'W' });

Comment: My apologies, it should be `if(is_null($this->result)){ return 'W'; } `

Comment: Still same sir only that line,

Comment: Last time for good measure: `if(is_null($this->result)){ return 'W'; } `

Comment: it returning this error message App\Score::getGrade must return a relationship instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176926/discussion-between-benjamin-dowson-and-grace).